# How can I make System processes run on only the first two cores?

Tags: windows-10, cpu

As the title suggests, I need a way to make System processes (such as ntoskrnl.exe) in Windows 10 to run on only the first two cores. This is because my CPU (AMD Phenom II X2 B59) can unlock two extra cores, but when I do this, windows will not boot. If I can tell the system to permanently run all of its processes on only the first two (stable) cores, then I most likely won't have any trouble booting.

Note that setting the process affinity won't work because:

1) It's not a permanent fix (doesn't occur when booting), and

2) The affinity of those processes cannot be changed.

Answer (score 2):

AMD produced Quad Core AMD Phenom II CPUs (X4) and during testing, they selected the cpus were some cores have issues and disabled the damaged cores to be still able to sell them as Dual Core CPU.

Only is some cases, where they have a large request for a special Dual Core CPU, they used Quad Core CPUs which are fine, but still disabled 2 cores.

Looks like you got a CPU with the damaged cores. Here you can't do anything. This is pure luck if you got a fine CPU that can have 4 cores or if you have a version because it has issues. If you want 4 cores, buy a AMD Phenom II X4 and not the AMD Phenom II X2.